# Hill Climbing or Harmony Search algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to develop a course timetabling system using Harmony Search algorithm.
Met a programmer in university and he told me I do not understand Harmony Search algorithm at all. I admit that I don't get Harmony search algorithm. He suggested me to use Hill Climbing cause its much simpler.

1. What are the differences between these 2 algorithms?
2. Any papers/ source that I can use so I can fully understand these algorithms?

Comment: Just a note: Hill Climbing does not usually refer to a specific algorithm, but rather a whole family of problem-solving approaches with a "hill climbing" aspect in common. Typically, the solution space can be conceptualized as a multidimensional plane with peaks and valleys for local maxima/minima. Often times, a good solution can be viewed as a relatively high maxima. Hence the idea of hill-climbing: a climber can look for higher ground nearby. Related keywords/concepts/algorithms: follow gradient descent curve, simulated annealing, genetic algorithms, neural networks, etc.

Comment: Both of them are easy to express the intuition but hard to fully understand. Papers/references can be found in their wiki pages. [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmony_search) and [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing).

Comment: Asking questions about the differences between things is, in general, not particularly appropriate for [so]. I suggest you focus your question on asking about harmony search (as the basic idea of hill climbing is fairly trivial, perhaps harmony search is too, but I haven't dealt with it before). Also, your second question is off topic for [so] (as per the [help/on-topic]), so I suggest you remove / rephrase it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this site: https://sites.google.com/a/hydroteq.com/www/
First you may need a small background about metaheuristic algorithms and NP-Hard/NP-Complete problems. Google-it!!
Hill Climbing is actually the easiest 'cause doesn't have parametrization, but not always you can get the best solution, it might get trapped in a local optimum, so Harmony Search (from population-based family) can solve this issue.
Hope the site helps.